# Electron Builder NSIS Create a shortcut in startup

Tags: windows, electron, nsis, electron-builder

I am using Electron Builder to generate an NSIS installer for windows. I need the installer to create a shortcut in the startup menu.

How can I do that?

This is Electron Builder documentation about NSIS Scripts. https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script

Where should I put code to be executed after installing the application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to do this by putting the code that creates the shortcut in side the `customInstall` macro in a custom instllaer script for NSIS

In `package.json`

```
"build": {
  "nsis": {
      "include": "build/installer.nsh",
  },
```

This is to be able to use a custom script.

And in the `build/installer.nsh`

```
!macro customInstall
      CreateShortCut "$SMSTARTUP\filename.lnk" "$INSTDIR\filename.exe"
!macroend
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the "createStartMenuShortcut" option in the top-level nsis key in your electron-builder config:

```
"build": {
  "nsis": {
    "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
  },
  //Rest of the config
}
```

You can find more config options in [the docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis)

Comment: I want to create a shortcut at the startup in start menu

Comment: This does not answer the question