# Electron app not showing in notification settings

Tags: notifications, electron, windows-10

We have written an electron app. It shows notifications (Win10). Once the app was spamming with a lot of notifications so I switched them off from the notification tile.

[image: As seen in the image]

I wanted to enable them back. So I went to notification settings and I could not find my app in the list.

PS: We are using electron Notification module and we are also calling app.setAppUserModelId("OurAppName")

Answer (score 3):

This is a semi-known issue where electron applications are simply missing from Windows Notifications Center.

Try changing

```
app.setAppserModelId("yourAppName");
```

To

```
app.on('ready', () => app.setAppUserModelId("Your.AppName"));
```

I had the same issue recently and this did the trick for me, I found the solution here:
https://github.com/Automattic/simplenote-electron/pull/2483

In other iterations of similar issues, there is a workaround to enable notifications again which can be found here:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24330#issuecomment-650546142

For Electron you can find the event 'ready' here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-ready

Comment: thanks for the links shared.. Apart from moving app.setAppUserModelId to 'ready' , i also had to edit vue.config.js file to include appId

Comment: you save my hours

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've a shortcut for your app in the start menu.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh802762(v=vs.85)

> Without a valid shortcut installed in the Start screen or in All Programs, you cannot raise a toast notification from a desktop app.

For electtron-builder there's a setting to force shortcut creation: [Electron Builder NSIS Create a shortcut in startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422871/electron-builder-nsis-create-a-shortcut-in-startup)

node-notifer can force-create shortcut too, check basic example code:

```
//run with Node
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
notifier.notify('Message');
```

Also, it's important to have `appId` match one which is in `setAppUserModelId`. For Electron builder, for windows build, `appId` is set in

```
"win": {
  ....
  "appId": "MyApp"
},
```